# 5 hp air compressor wiring

Tags: wiring, compressor, air

5 hp 80 gal 208/230 volt air compressor, amps 18.6-17.5, LR amps -95, KW- 2.98
Located 80-100 feet from panel--looking for wire size and breaker size    thanks   John

on 230V circuit
hp listed on tank is 4.7
no FLA

Comment: Are you on 230/240V (common) or 208V (rarer, unless you're in NYC)?  Also, are you putting a cord on the air compressor, or hardwiring it to the wall?

Comment: Is the 2.98 KW  part of the compressor or a separate dryer unit? Any installation instructions?

Comment: @jack 2.98kw will be the motor wattage true. Or closer to 4hp this is typical with vacuum cleaners and air compressors to lie about horsepower.

Comment: @EdBeal  OK.  I thought it was a dryer for the air compressor. Some of the factories I worked in had them,

Comment: 230/240 V, in Arizona, HP advertised on tank is 4.7(ha,ha)

Comment: @johnzimmermann that "amps" figure is right off the motor nameplate I take it?

Comment: @johnzimmermann in fact, can you get us a photo of the nameplate on the motor please?

Comment: @threephaseeel using the amps off the motor name plate for anything other than overloads would be a code violation,  table values are to be used based on the horsepower and voltage. these manufacturers lie about horsepower but the kw rating can be used. This is explained in code but most internet electricians don’t know the code specifies this. Separate overload device-430.6.2 & 430.32.1.  Size of conductors 430.6.1, & 430.22. If a MFG gives a lower value to be used this is proof that there motor is not the advertised horsepower as I stated in my answer.

Comment: @EdBeal -- I'm kind of wondering if this is under motor rules (HP governs, as per the main body of 430.6) or appliance rules, basically (430.6 Ex 3, which permits amperage to govern for listed motor-operated appliances marked with both HP/KW and amps)

Comment: I provided the code reference that for conductor sizing if horsepower is used a 5 Hp motor is 28 amps I have not 2 but 2 references that state book value is used NOT name tag for conductor sizing, the nameplate is used for separate motor overload protection an there is yet another table for the max breaker size. As it is a motor article 430 is all about motors if you do not know the code please don’t tell folks how to select the proper sizes I have references and reasoning and why the name plate value is not allowed for amperage.

Answer (score 1):

Do they provide the FLA?
Air compressor vendors lie about horse power!!!
Going by code we would use the fla book value 5hp or 28 amps plus 125% because it is a motor load or 35 amps requiring a 35 but probably a 40 amp breaker and #8 wire.

In reality your fla is probably going to be closer to 13 amps ( 2.98kw /240v) and that will be fine on a 12 awg circuit with a 20 amp circuit breaker.

Why do I say air compressor (and vacuum cleaner) companies lie?
With locked rotor no work is being done and the definition of 1 horse power is the work of 746w. They put the LR value and at locked rotor no work is done.